# error in visual studio while running command run serve? why

Tags: vue.js, visual-studio-code, node-modules

PS C:\Users\Rasul Rafik\Desktop\Courses\Vue.js\Udemy\Section - 8 - Component comunication\cmp-communication-assignment-problem> npm run serve

> vue-first-app@0.1.0 serve
> vue-cli-service serve

INFO  Starting development server...

ERROR  Failed to compile with 2 errors                           2:45:19 pm

[eslint] ESLint is not a constructor

You may use special comments to disable some warnings.
Use // eslint-disable-next-line to ignore the next line.
Use /* eslint-disable */ to ignore all warnings in a file.
Error: Child compilation failed:
[eslint] ESLint is not a constructor

- child-compiler.js:169
  [cmp-communication-assignment-problem]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-c    ompiler.js:169:18
- Compiler.js:551 finalCallback
  [cmp-communication-assignment-problem]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:551:5
- Compiler.js:577
  [cmp-communication-assignment-problem]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:577:11
- Compiler.js:1200
  [cmp-communication-assignment-problem]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1200:17
- task_queues:95 processTicksAndRejections
  node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5
- task_queues:64 runNextTicks
  node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3
- timers:449 process.processImmediate
  node:internal/timers:449:9

ERROR in [eslint] ESLint is not a constructor

ERROR in   Error: Child compilation failed:
[eslint] ESLint is not a constructor

- child-compiler.js:169
  [cmp-communication-assignment-problem]/[html-webpack-plugin]/lib/child-c    ompiler.js:169:18
- Compiler.js:551 finalCallback
  [cmp-communication-assignment-problem]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:551:5
- Compiler.js:577
  [cmp-communication-assignment-problem]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:577:11
- Compiler.js:1200
  [cmp-communication-assignment-problem]/[webpack]/lib/Compiler.js:1200:17
- task_queues:95 processTicksAndRejections
  node:internal/process/task_queues:95:5
- task_queues:64 runNextTicks
  node:internal/process/task_queues:64:3
- timers:449 process.processImmediate
  node:internal/timers:449:9

1 ERROR in child compilations (Use 'stats.children: true' resp. '--stats-children' for more details)
webpack compiled with 3 errors

I run the command but error coming

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.